# How to make a new line in the array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

`$arr = array("", "Name: Grigoriy /n Lastname: Alexandrov /n Email: alex123@gmail.com");`

This /n does not work when I want to put the data on the screen.
I want to show this:

[image]

but it shows me like this:

[image]

> I use AJAX

Comment: Two problems. Newlines are `\n`, not `/n`. And If you're displaying it in an HTML document, it won't show them anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "I use AJAX"? Can you show the code for the way you're outputting this array currently?

Comment: @Don'tPanic `function loading() {
 $("#result").text('Loading...');
}

function success(data) {
 $("#result").text(data);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#find').bind("click", function() {
  var select = $("select[name='names']").val();
  $.ajax({
   url: "base.php",
   type: "GET",
   data: ({ value: select }),
   dataType: "html",
   beforeSend: loading,
   success: success
  });
 });
});`

Comment: Add `white-space: pre-line` to the style for your result area. (And correct the `/n`s to `\n`s.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use: `/n` but you should use: `\n`

Add this to css where you are showing results:

`white-space: pre-line;`

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you have to use `<br>` tags to add a new line. Or you can use `nl2br()` function to convert `\n` to `<br>` tags.

Comment: I use **AJAX**, \n or <br> does not work when I want to show it on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `/n` but you have to use `\n`
Please use this

```
$arr = array("", "Name: Grigoriy \nLastname: Alexandrov \nEmail: alex123@gmail.com");
```

instead of

```
$arr = array("", "Name: Grigoriy /n Lastname: Alexandrov /n Email: alex123@gmail.com");
```